# TypeError array.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I'm building a React app that pulls data from an S3 bucket.

```
const Products = () => {
const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    getBucket().then( data => setPhotos({photos: data}))
  }, [])
return (
    <Fragment>
        {photos.length === 0 ? (
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            ) : (
                photos.map((photo)=>(
                    <ProductCard img={photo.Key} />
                ))
            )
        }
    </Fragment>
)}
```

I get TypeError: photos.map is not a function;

This is what I get back from S3.

```
{"photos":[{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(1).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"211fa91695f9cf5c0db52b7d8696a6b5\"","Size":116003,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"},{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(2).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"a27e32e9bdf275b98dd6b12d747c7ff4\"","Size":142108,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"},{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(3).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"2dae6a85ffb74130317dee3577ab42c5\"","Size":159906,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"},{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(4).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"f3f2f5716f2d0da2f4f7d756a1302801\"","Size":128466,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"},{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(5).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"c4135e0516e6fc5f17fbcea05bbb0aa5\"","Size":125733,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"},{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(6).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"2952dcf05490e21617176280bebdd5a2\"","Size":122684,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"},{"Key":"Blusa-con-tejido-y-Pantalon-(7).jpg","LastModified":"2020-10-14T23:03:56.000Z","ETag":"\"1506f3196095edd66a0d4c85936a302f\"","Size":106216,"StorageClass":"STANDARD"}]}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. The issue has been that I used setPhotos incorrectly. My previous code was:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getBucket().then(data => setPhotos({photos: data}))
}, [])
```

The correct code should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getBucket().then(data => setPhotos(data))
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `photos` state to `data` but `data` is not an array–it's an object with a property called `photos`, and THAT is the array. Change your `useEffect` to use that.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getBucket().then( data => setPhotos({photos: data.photos}))
  }, [])
```

Comment: Yeah, you’re correct except for the data.photos piece. “data” is an array in my use case, but I was not passing it to setPhotos correctly. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

`setPhotos` is wrong. you are currently passed json `{photos: data}`. you should pass the array as a param of the `setPhotos`

```
useEffect(() => {
    getBucket().then( data => setPhotos(data.photos))
  }, [])
```

Comment: I may have made my issue unclear by stating what I am getting back from S3. The code snippet above that says “photos”, is the state of my component. The data I get back from S3 is an array of objects. It doesn’t have a property of “photos”.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the data type msgs is not an array. if you doing this
with "data" object from an API response. map is only available to arrays
since it lives on the array prototype array.prototype.map.
You cannot use map on an object.

like this:
const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([{}])